# Apache not receiving a referal_url?

Tags: html, apache, url, tracking

I have an Apache server that receives around 7000 visits per day, but only about 1300 of 7000 receive the referal_url from the user agent.

Is there anything I can do about this?

I'd like to know where these clicks are coming from for fraud purposes.

Comment: Have you considered that not all requests will have a referral URL? And that it's quite easy to fake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force a user agent to send anything.  it obeys it's own rules.  Also note that if the user types in your URL directly, no referral header would ever be generated.

However, you do get an IP address which you can check.